# Compile a program with local file embedded as a string variable?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, include

Question should say it all.

Let's say there's a local file "mydefaultvalues.txt", separated from the main project. In the main project I want to have something like this:

```
 char * defaultvalues = " ... "; // here should be the contents of mydefaultvalues.txt
```

And let the compiler swap `" ... "` with the actual contents of `mydefaultvalues.txt`. Can this be done? Is there like a compiler directive or something?

Comment: What platform are you on? If Windows, read up on resource files.

Comment: @ildjarn yes I'm on Windows, but I don't want the defaults to be resource-hacked.

Comment: If it's absolutely necessary you do it this way I suggest looking for a tool the directly stuffs any file into an .obj file (or equiv.). Compile, link, use. no mess, no fuss.

Comment: If they want to hack them they'll just change it in the binary. If they have enough time and motivation they'll patch your code to bake brownies.

Comment: Thank you @CaptainObvlious I know what the real ballers can do; it's just I don't want to expose it to `tards with resource hackers that's all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to achieve compile-time trickery like this is to write a simple script in some interpreted programming language(e.g. Python, Ruby or Perl will do great) which does a simple search and replace. Then just run the script before compiling.

Define your own #pramga XYZ directive which the script looks for and replaces it with the code that declares the variable with file contents in a string.

```
char * defaultvalues = ...
```

where ... contains the text string read from the given text file. Be sure to compensate for line length, new lines, string formatting characters and other special characters.

Edit: lvella beat me to it with far superior approach - embrace the tools your environment supplies you. In this case a tool which does string search and replace and feed a file to it.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the need to scrub the contents. I expanded it a little for you.

Answer (score 4):

Not exactly, but you could do something like this:

defaults.h:

```
#define DEFAULT_VALUES "something something something"
```

code.c:

```
#include "defaults.h"

char *defaultvalues = DEFAULT_VALUES;
```

Where defaults.h could be generated, or otherwise created however you were planning to do it.  The pre-processor can only do so much.  Making your files in a form that it will understand will make things much easier.

Comment: The problem here is that DEFAULT_VALUES needs to be multi-line which requires wrapping each line in double quotes, and escape all other.

Comment: You could just include the text file assuming you format it properly.  `const char* Stuff = 
{
#include "stuff.txt"
};
`

Answer (score 3):

The trick I did, on Linux, was to have in the Makefile this line:

```
defaultvalues.h: defaultvalues.txt
    xxd -i defaultvalues.txt > defaultvalues.h
```

Then you could include:

```
#include "defaultvalues.h"
```

There is defined both `unsigned char defaultvalues_txt[];` with the contents of the file, and `unsigned int defaultvalues_txt_len;` with the size of the file.

Note that `defaultvalues_txt` is not null-terminated, thus, not considered a C string. But since you also have the size, this should not be a problem.

EDIT:

A small variation would allow me to have a null-terminated string:

```
echo "char defaultvalues[] = { " `xxd -i < defaultvalues.txt` ", 0x00 };" > defaultvalues.h
```

Obviously will not work very well if the null character is present inside the file `defaultvalues.txt`, but that won't happen if it is plain text.

Answer (score -1):

Late answer I know but I don't think any of the current answers address what the OP is trying to accomplish although zxcdw came really close.

All any 7 year old has to do is load your program into a hex editor and hit CTRL-S. If the text is in your executable code (or vicinity) or application resource they can find it and edit it.

If you want to prevent the *general* public from changing a resource or static data just encrypt it, stuff it in a resource then decrypt it at runtime. Try DES for something small to start with.

Comment: What means it will have the key sometime in memory, what takes a 15 years old to find it and decrypt the file. If just to obfuscate the data, a XOR is much more appropriate. Security-wise, having a cipher text together with its key is as good as having the plain text.